# Chrome F12 issues

Tags: google-chrome, desktop

Every time I press `F12` on a website the query made to that website fails (the one in the image below) but as soon as I press `F12 again` the website redirects and it works. Help me please !

*(Not working in localhost too)*

[image: This image]